# socket.io doesnt work on the server but on my localhost it does

Tags: javascript, github, socket.io, server, localhost

I did a chat room with socket.io and express. It was working on my localhost but when I upload it on github, it is not working.
I searched lot of time on the web but found nothing so if you can help me, it will be fantastic.

code : html (client )

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Chat with your friend</title>
    <style>
    #chat{
        height:500px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chat"></div>
        <form id="send-message">
            <input size="35" id="message"></input>
            <input type = "submit"></input>
        </form>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
        jQuery(function($){
            var socket = io.connect();
            var $messageForm = $('#send-message');
            var $messageBox = $('#message');
            var $chat = $('#chat');


            $messageForm.submit(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                socket.emit('send message', $messageBox.val());
                $messageBox.val('');
            });

            socket.on('new message', function(data){
                $chat.append(data + "<br/>");
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js (server)

```
var express = require('express'),
app = express(),
server = require('http').createServer(app),
io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

    server.listen(8080);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
socket.on('send message', function(data){
    io.sockets.emit('new message', data);       
}); 
});
```

package.json:

```
{
"name": "Chat",
"version": "0.1.0",
"priviate": true,
"dependencies": {
    "socket.io": "1.4.6",
    "express": "4.14.0"
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "upload on Github" mean?  Where are you running your server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting code on github won't run the server for you.

[HyperDev](http://hyperdev.com) might be what you want.

It will run your node app for free. Just don't count on it being up 100% of the time.

I copied your code into a [project](https://hyperdev.com/#!/project/holly-bush).

Had to make a few small changes to get it going on hyperdev:

- now listens on port 3000
- now loads jquery from the https source rather than http
- you mistyped 'private' in package.json ;)

To view the running site click on 'Show', top left.

You can copy this to your own project by clicking on 'holly-bush', top left, and 'Remix Project'. Then you can make changes to that one and it will refresh the server for you.

It's a great way to test out node stuff.